# How do I stop floats from wrapping?

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent the picture from jumping down, when the window gets smaller? I know I haven't used `float: right`, but that's because the content was too far away from the navi bar then. Do I have to use another div, make that float on the right, and then center the content into it by using margin auto? Or is there any way to prevent browsers from letting the content "jump"?

```css
body {
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
}
#links {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
#rechts {
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="links"></div>
<div id="rechts"></div>
```

Comment: please add some code to your question or a jsdiddle, or show us what you have tried

Comment: Post code here. And your link is not working.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it clearer and only include the necessary HTML and CSS to display the problem. I also made sure there were no external links as they can break over time. You should see the edit once it is peer reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use **float**.

**Float** depend on width of browsers.Your picture will jump down when browser not enough width.

You should use attribute **Position** ( absolute or fixed)

You can see this examble: (I use **Fixed** in this examble)

```
position:fixed;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xe7jxwra/

Some information about Position in CSS:

- Fixed positioned elements are removed from the normal flow. The document and other elements behave like the fixed positioned element does not exist
- An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is **html**

In your request, you should set your parent of content to Relative, and set your content is Absolute

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed the your navigation bar and put padding-left (navigation bar's width 300px) to the #rechts and remove the margin-left. Like below

```
#links {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: 8px 0 10px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
}



#rechts {  
  padding-left: 300px;
  font-size: medium;
}
```